# How do I prevent my table from moving with the scroll & How to keep it centered?

Tags: html, css

I have a website I'm working on to teach myself how to use CSS, HTML, and JS all together, but I'm running into issues!

Here is a link to what I have: https://codepen.io/ckneeland/pen/dypMLVe

Here is the code that I have:

```js
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  particles: {
    number: { value: 80, density: { enable: true, value_area: 800 } },
    color: { value: "#ffffff" },
    shape: {
      type: "circle",
      stroke: { width: 0, color: "#000000" },
      polygon: { nb_sides: 5 },
      image: { src: "img/github.svg", width: 100, height: 100 }
    },
    opacity: {
      value: 0.2,
      random: false,
      anim: { enable: false, speed: 1, opacity_min: 0.1, sync: false }
    },
    size: {
      value: 3,
      random: true,
      anim: { enable: false, speed: 40, size_min: 0.1, sync: false }
    },
    line_linked: {
      enable: true,
      distance: 150,
      color: "#ffffff",
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: 1
    },
    move: {
      enable: true,
      speed: 6,
      direction: "none",
      random: false,
      straight: false,
      out_mode: "out",
      bounce: false,
      attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 1200 }
    }
  },
  interactivity: {
    detect_on: "canvas",
    events: {
      onhover: { enable: true, mode: ["repulse", "bubble"] },
      onclick: { enable: true, mode: "push" },
      resize: true
    },
    modes: {
      grab: { distance: 400, line_linked: { opacity: 1 } },
      bubble: { distance: 400, size: 40, duration: 2, opacity: 8, speed: 3 },
      repulse: { distance: 200, duration: 0.4 },
      push: { particles_nb: 4 },
      remove: { particles_nb: 2 }
    }
  },
  retina_detect: true
});
var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats();
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
stats.domElement.style.left = "0px";
stats.domElement.style.top = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector(".js-count-particles");
update = function () {
  stats.begin();
  stats.end();
  if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 179.7deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 2%, rgba(26,166,198,1) 90.1% );
}
canvas {
  display: block;
} 

td {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.resize {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.resize2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.center-table {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%; /*May have to change to include more apps in the future*/
  right: 30%; /*May have to change to include more apps in the future*/
}

/* ---- particles.js container ---- */
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 179.7deg, #7d4eb9 2%, rgba(26,166,198,1) 90.1% );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Connor's Particles</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div id="particles-js" ></div>
    <table class="center-table">
      <tr>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/Snapchat.png" alt="Snapchat"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/YouTube.png" alt="YouTube"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/TikTok.png" alt="TikTok"></td>
        <td><img class="resize2" src="Images/Google2.png" alt="Google"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/Venmo2.png" alt="Venmo"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/Reddit2.png" alt="Reddit"></td>
        <td><img class="resize" src="Images/LinkedIn.png" alt="LinkedIn"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="height: 3000px; background-color: whitesmoke;">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

<!--#7d4eb9-->
```

Unfortunately the pictures wont load in on CodePen, but that's not really an issue. How can I can stop the table from moving when I scroll? I put it inside a div, so I'm really confused as to how it's even moving in the first place. Along with that, how can I dynamically center the table? The solution I have at the moment just centers it on my own screen, but not others. Any thoughts?

The JS is used for the particle animation using ParticlesJS. You probably don't need to look at that but StackOverflow wanted me to include it.

Comment: The table doesn't seem to move when I scroll. What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you mean table is 'moving'. With position: fixed. The table remains stationary at that position during page scroll. You want the table to be moving along with the scroll??
Following are the two solutions based on your requirements.

To keep it centered with table remaining stationary at a position with position fixed:

CSS

```
.center-table {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%; //new addition
    transform: translate(-50%, 0); //new addition
}
```

To make Table scroll along with the page and remain at the center

CSS

```
.center-table {
    margin: 0 auto; //new addition
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative; //changed fixed to relative
}
```